# Is there an Android best practice for auto-completing addresses in offline-mode?

Tags: android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview, street-address, offline-mode

I have an app which requires the registration of companies.Part of the registration requires the companies address. 

I was wanting to auto-complete / suggest the address using:

> GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions()

(or equivalent) to minimise clashes with remote database to prevent clashes of names and address in the server database when merging. 
The server/back-end is being developed separately and they are using the google autocomplete for addresses added using the web services.

The app is sometimes used offline. Currently the app checks if internet before doing complete, otherwise the user must enter the address themselves. This can led to companies being created twice with differently worded addresses being created

The app is currently being used in the US and is rolled out in multiple states.

**1. Can the info from google auto-complete be used without access to the internet?**

(Such as a downloadable database of addresses?)

**2. Is there a way to cache addresses in a localised area?**

**3. Is there an alternative library to GeoDataApi (which follows the same address format)?**

Comment: @Mureinik, Have No Display, Jeeped, David L, or Avadhani Y. Could you please offer some feedback rather than just flagging the question? How can I change the question to result in "less possible answers" or short answer formats? The question was starred 3 times shortly after being asked before the question was closed, so there does appear to be some interest/benefit for the SO community.